# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended oracle database

Tags: oracle, join, sql-update

The following query run success with SQL Server Express 12 database, but It will throw an error with oracle database:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

```
UPDATE ENTITY SET REQUIREDRESOLUTION = 0.005
FROM ENTITY INNER JOIN FUNC ON ENTITY.FUNCCODE = FUNC.FUNCCODE 
WHERE  (FUNC.TEMPLATE = 4) AND ((ENTITY.CATEGORYCODE = - 5) OR (ENTITY.CATEGORYCODE = - 7))
```

Could anyone help? How can I modified this query to able to use for both the SQL Server and Oracle database?

Comment: Does Oracle support that UPDATE FROM syntax?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
update entity e set 
  e.requiredresolution = 0.005
  where exists (select null
                from func f
                where f.funccode = e.funccode
                  and f.template = 4
               )
    and e.categorycode in (-5, -7);
```

Comment: I just add another condition to my question. I try out your query and it seems to work for oracle but it does not seem to like the syntax when I try it with MySQL to access the SQL database.

Comment: @anhnguyen1104 . . . This answers the question that you originally asked (presumably).  If that is true, you should accept it.  Changing the question after it has been answered is rude, because it can attract downvotes.  Stack Overflow is not a dialog site to arrive at the perfect question.  It is a Q&A site to answer the questions that are asked.

Comment: @Littlefoot Sorry, I just change my question back to original. But your answer seems to have a syntax problem when I try to use it to access the SQL database.

Comment: What kind of a problem?

Comment: @Littlefoot never mind, it is my mistake. I look at the wrong code. I will vote for your answer now. Thanks